# Select query doesn't work when data is in Arabic, using dynamic query with parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

In **asp.net c#** code inside **Visual studio**, I developed a  search button. When I try to run the code it's return nothing while writing the code. I think the problem is that the `stat_leger` is written in Arabic.

```
SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];
    para[0] = new SqlParameter("@stat_leger", ddlACCcode.SelectedValue);
    para[1] = new SqlParameter("@branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);
    para[2] = new SqlParameter("@from", db.getDate(txtFrom.Text));
    para[3] = new SqlParameter("@to", db.getDate(txtTo.Text));

 DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText("Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_leger = @stat_leger and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to ORDER BY stat_date ", para);

GridView1.DataSource = dtreport;
GridView1.DataBind();
float GTotal = 0;
float GTotalcrd = 0;
float GTotaldeb = 0;
```

It worked when I  tried to write the same select inside the sql server. But with arabic I used `N` and it's return records.

```
   Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code =     
    stat_trans_code 
      where stat_sub_leger = N'الصندوق' and branch= N'الفرع الرئيسي' and stat_date between '2013-12-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-12-05 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY stat_date ;
```

I tried to write it in select as but still not working :

```
          DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText("Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_sub_leger = N'@stat_sub_leger' and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to ORDER BY stat_date ", para);
```

Comment: Check character set of the field or table. Use quote ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query, for sample:

```
Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_leger like '%' + @stat_leger + '%' OR  branch like '%' + @branch + '%' AND stat_date between @from and @to ORDER BY stat_date ", para);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work this way:

```
para[0] = new SqlParameter("@stat_leger", "N'"+ddlACCcode.SelectedValue+"'")
```

and then use your query from within asp.net:

```
DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText(
    "Select * from PostedVoucher join transactions on trans_code = stat_trans_code where stat_sub_leger = N'@stat_sub_leger' and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to ORDER BY stat_date ",
    para);
```

then it's always advised to print your final SQL command to see whether it matches the correct form of SQL command